# discord.py: self.after(error) TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have been working to add music functionality to my bot and I think I am almost done with the queuing the music part but I encountered this error. I believe the error stems from the `playSong` call in `queue` function or the `vc.play` method in `queueCheck`.

Here is the traceback:

```
[youtube] c1s3Iekns9k: Downloading webpage
2022-08-30 13:57:39 ERROR    discord.player Calling the after function failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Horus-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 711, in _call_after
    self.after(error)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Here is my code:

```py
players = {}
queues = {}

class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  def queueCheck(self, id, vc):
    if queues[id] != []:      # if server queue not empty
      stream = queues[id].pop(0, None)
      players[id] = stream
      vc.play(stream)

  

  async def playSong(self, ctx, url):
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio",
                    'default_search':'auto'}
    
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
      if 'entries' in info:        # if no url is input
        url2 = info['entries'][0]['formats'][0]['url']
      elif 'formats' in info:      # if url is passed
        url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
      stream = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)

    return stream
  
  @commands.command()
  async def play(self, ctx, *, url):
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()

    stream = await self.playSong(ctx, url)
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    vc = ctx.voice_client
    players[guild.id] = stream
    vc.play(stream, after=lambda: self.queueCheck(guild, vc))
    

  @commands.command()
  async def queue(self, ctx, url):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    stream = await self.playSong(ctx, url)

    if guild.id in queues:
      queues[guild.id].append(stream)
    else:
      queues[guild.id] = [stream]

    await ctx.send("Song queued.")
```

Comment: Please read [mre]. "I believe the error stems from the playSong call in queue function or the vc.play method in queueCheck." Then the first thing to do is **test** that belief, by [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code. For example, can you cause the problem if you make the code only try to `queue` songs (and don't worry about whether they actually play, but only do the minimum setup work)? Can you cause the problem if you simply call e.g. `await self.playSong(ctx, url)` from a command, without worrying about the actual queuing?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have edited in the reprex now. Thank you for your attention. And as for the debugging portion.... I cannot believe I had forgotten to check whether the queue by itself could play the first song or not. Turns out it can. So that narrows down the issue to the playlist somehow not being able to play the next song, which is because of the `<lambda>() typeError` . So I am back to where I started.

Comment: Try setting an argument to the lambda function you have in the `play` function like `vc.play(stream, after=lambda e: self.queueCheck(guild, vc))`. In the source code, the after function you pass is called with an instance of `Exception`. Which probably means you have another error in the run process. I imagine it stems from you storing guild ids in a list instead of a dictionary, so when you try to access the queue for a specific guild, you may want to use a dictionary for that too. Or it may be something with the source. I'm not sure, never played with voice which is why this is a comment.

Comment: Thank you for simplifying it @3nws. The first one kicked off the command perfectly. I just had to add `guild.id` as an argument instead of `guild` in the call to `queueCheck`.